# JAVA JCheckBox takes 2 clicks to check and 1 click to uncheck

Tags: java

The problem i have is that my JCheckBox need 2 clicks ( not double click ) to check and 1 click to uncheck. The rest of the code is perfectly working.

```
JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox(new ImageIcon("images/check.png"));
check.setOpaque(false);   

check.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
        for(int i = 0; i < tempPanel.length; i++)       
            if(check.getParent().equals(tempPanel[i])){
                if(!check.isSelected()){
                    JLabel tempLabel = new JLabel("Command "+(i+1));
                    tempLabel.setFont(new Font("Franchise",Font.BOLD,122));
                    tempLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

                    tempPanel[i].setBorder(lineBorder);
                    tempPanel2[i].add(tempLabel);
                    secondScreenPanel.add(tempPanel2[i]);
                    secondScreenPanel.revalidate();
                    secondScreenPanel.repaint();
                    break;
                }

                if(check.isSelected()){
                     tempPanel[i].setBorder(null);
                     secondScreenPanel.remove(tempPanel2[i]);
                     tempPanel2[i].removeAll();
                     secondScreenPanel.revalidate();
                     secondScreenPanel.repaint();    
                }
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a MouseListener.

A `JCheckBox` is designed to be used with an `ItemListener` or `ActionListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Check Boxes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/) for more information and examples

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the JCheckBox withou listener, create a layout into you mainframe and check this code, It works fine for me:

```
    jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();

    jCheckBox1.setText("jCheckBox1");
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new     javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(139, 139, 139)
            .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
            .addContainerGap(180, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
            .addContainerGap(227, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
```